# AWS lambda can we version from another version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

is there a way to version from another version copy in AWS Lambda instead of creating new function or versioning from unqualified latest ?

> Say we have versions like  Version1, Version2, Version3, Version4 etc
> and latest is Version4

***Now we need to user Version2 and have to create a new version on top of it like Version2_1***

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not using different lambda? is it for the blue green deployment?

Comment: yes, as there are chances of different vendors at diff versions and the latest may not be supported in lower versions, and if it is a new lambda, again we have to maintain seperately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. AWS doesn't support this feature natively, but you can export Version2 of the function, re-upload it, and then make changes on top of that.

Comment: Thanks jellycsc, i think this will work. can we achieve this using the stackformation template or do we need to using manual process

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tool you are talking about. The manual process definitely works.